# Discord.py - Buttons side by side

Tags: python, button, discord.py, bots

I've created some buttons for my Discord bot. The buttons now show up underneath each other while I'd rather have them side-by-side instead.
I tried using an ActionRow for this, but that doesn't seem to change anything.
Fyi, I'm using Discord.py 1.7.3, so not v2.0.

The current code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import time
from discord_components import *

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    button = Button(
        style=ButtonStyle.blue,
        custom_id="primary",
        label="Blue button",
    )
    button2 = Button(
        style=ButtonStyle.red,
        custom_id="secondary",
        label="Red button",
    )
    action_row = ActionRow(components=[button, button2])
    await ctx.send("Hello World!", components=action_row)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

So the answer was fairly simple.
For those who wonder...

Replace:

```
    action_row = ActionRow(components=[button, button2])
    await ctx.send("Hello World!", components=action_row)
```

By:

```
    action_row = ActionRow(button, button2)
    await ctx.send("Hello World!", components=[action_row])
```

There's no need to add a list to the ActionRow.

Answer (score 0):

Last I knew discord.py was abandoned. I have used [pycord](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/index.html) since then. Although I have not used buttons before they have a row argument for their buttons. I'd suggest taking a look at pycord or maybe whatever discord.py docs you are using for a `row` argument to buttons. See their docs [`here`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=button#discord.ui.button)

Example:

```
button = Button(
    style=ButtonStyle.blue,
    custom_id="primary",
    label="Blue button",
    row=1,
)
```

Comment: It was abandoned, then "un-abandoned". There should be a way out there. Either way, is it tough to migrate from discord.py to pycord? I've got quite some commands already.

Comment: Pycord is a fork of discord.py so just need to remove discord.py from your env/venv and install pycord